# jQuery - Click and open

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, methods

I'm am using jQuery and bootstrap.

The thing i want is, when I click on an `h5` inside one column, another div opens in another column, and when h5 is clicked again it closes (I haven't attempted that code yet)
I have several of theese rows.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h5 class="select">2013 - </h5>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I can't seem to get it right when I merge those to together. Like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h5 class="select">2013 - 2013</h5>

        <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
            <p>Content1</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

But that dosen't get the layout I would like.

My script look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var dropdown = $('.dropdown');
dropdown.hide();

$('.select').on('click', function(){
    $(this)
    .next('.dropdown')
    .slideDown(400)
    console.log('.dropdown');

})
```

});

I think the problem is that I'm using `next()`.
Is there another method that is more correct or a different approach?

Comment: `.next` means immediately following sibling. so the second one will work

Comment: `.next()` does not affect your layout. Can you create a jsfiddle of what you intend your layout to look like.

Comment: to make my understanding clear, when you click on .select class, dropdown class should show ..am i right ?

Comment: Well, no. But the script only works when I put in the same div 
(column - col-md-6)

Yes. exactly, when I click on .select,  .dropdown should show.

Comment: next means **immediately** following sibling, ie **very next sibling of each `.select`. Keep only the ones with a class `dropdown`.**

Answer (score 1):

I had solved this using the style="display:none;" property, as shown in the code below.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function _Toggle(div){

    if(document.getElementById(div).style.display == 'none'){
        document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none'; 
    }
}
</script>
```

Html:

```
<div class="foo_summary_header_1">
    <a href="#a147358" onclick="_Toggle('traits_12345');">Heading</a>
</div>


<div id="traits_12345" class="foo_traits" style="display:none;">
    <P>Body text that will be hidden by clicking the heading</P>
</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (updated)

html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h5 class="select">2013 - 2013</h5>    
        <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
            <p>Content1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(function() {
  $(".col-md-6 #dropdown").hide();
    $(document).on("click", ".col-md-6", function(e) {   
      $(e.target).siblings("#dropdown").toggle();
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/8DHB6/

Comment: Getting closer. It opens up all the hidden div. It should be only the one that is click on

Comment: Not certain about _"It opens up all the hidden div."_ ? At original post only _1_ "hidden div" described within `html`. If possible, can post full structure of `html` ? See updated post. Thanks

Comment: Sorry.. My description of the question wasn't adequate enough. A lesson to next time.
I've found my answer in another post (See answer). 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think the most simple solution is to use Bootstraps default functionality.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

             <h5 class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</h5>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Choice1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Choice2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Choice3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Choice..</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```